# Sed script that matches lines containing a string but does not include another string

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to write a sed script that replaces a portion of a line but only on lines that do not have a "$" sign in it.

For example, the file may look like

```
host=$myvar
param1=val1
param2=val2
host=abc
host=def
```

I want to replace the "host=abc" and "host=def" with "host=zzzzz" and ignore the "host=$myvar".  So the final output should look like:

```
host=$myvar
param1=val1
param2=val2
host=zzzzz
host=zzzzz
```

I tried the a few regex expressions, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using a pattern address:

```
sed '/\$/!s/^\(host=\).*/\1zzzz/' file
```

Results:

```
host=$myvar
param1=val1
param2=val2
host=zzzz
host=zzzz
```

Comment: Why do in 2 operations when single substitution can take care of it by using `^\(host=\)[^$]*` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
^host=([^\$].*?)$
```

- For this example, you need to use the multiline flag `/m` or go through it line by line. It uses `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning/end of the line
- `[^\$]` requires a character which is different than a `$`

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/8w6er9/2

---

If you cannot go through line by line, you can also use this regex:

```
(?:^|\r?\n)host=([^\$].*?)(?:\r?\n|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed` command for this:

```
sed -E 's/^(host=)[^$]+$/\1zzzzz/' file

host=$myvar
param1=val1
param2=val2
host=zzzzz
host=zzzzz
```

`[^$]+` is negated character class that matches 1 or more of any character that is not `$`